# Centre of Mass of a Body

Tags: integration

I know there is a formula for finding the centre of mass of a body, however I get different answers when applying the formula and without it.

Here is an example with my logic for the image shown below:

[image]

Because the bottom and top half of the trapezoid are the same, the centre of mass must lie somewhere on the x axis assuming uniformity of mass, meaning that:

$\int_a^{20}({\frac{7}{40}x+\frac{3}{2}}) dx - \int_0^{a}\left({\frac{7}{40}x+\frac{3}{2}}\right)dx = 0$

$ \implies \left(\frac{7}{80}(20)^2+30 - \frac{7}{80}a^2-1.5a\right)-\left(\frac{7}{80}a^2+\frac{3}{2}a\right)=65-\frac{7}{40}a^2-3a=0$

This way, we get:
$a \approx 12.521$.

When evaluating using the integral formula instead, the answer is closer to around 11. I don't understand why the answers differs! What is wrong with the logic used in my solution?

Comment: Your integral seems to be an area integral instead of first moment integral

Comment: @RezhaAdrianTanuharja Yes I know but if we assume the mass is uniformly distributed then we can say each infinitisimely small piece of area is of the same mass

Since the shape is the same below and above the x axis, we know the centre of mass lies somewhere on there.

Therefore wouldn't the centre of mass be at the point at which the area is 0, because each small piece of area corresponds to an infinitisimely small piece of mass, dm which when added up in total must be the same on both sides of that x value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral expression doesn't make sense. If your differential mass elements are vertical strips with height $2 y$ and width $d x$, where $y = a x + b$ as pictured ($a = \frac{7}{40}$, $b = \frac{3}{2}$), then the $x$-coordinate of the center of mass is

$$x_{CM} = \frac{\int_0^L x (2 y) d x}{\int_0^L (2 y) d x}$$

The bottom integral is just the area, which can be found simply by geometry:

$$(b + a L + b) L = a L^2 + 2 b L$$

The numerator is

$$2 \int_0^L (a x^2 + b x) d x = 2 \left[ \frac{1}{3} a x^3 + \frac{1}{2} b x^2 \right]_0^L$$

$$= \frac{2}{3} a L^3 + b L^2$$

The final result is

$$x_{CM} = \frac{2 a L^2 + 3 b L}{3 a L + 6 b} = L \left[ \frac{2 a L + 3 b}{3 a L + 6 b} \right]$$

Here, $L = 20$ so $a L = \frac{7}{2}$ (the difference in $y$-coordinate between the left and right ends). So, for your particular problem, $x_{CM} = \frac{23}{39} L$, which comes out to about $11.8$.

Comment: What I don't understand is why there is an x in the mass integral, and why we can't just simply take the area and make sure it is equal

Surely if mass is uniform and mass is equal below and above the y axis, wouldn't the centre of mass lie on the x axis and then be the point at which the area of the left piece is equal to that of the right?

What difference does it make adding up mass and area in this case if mass is uniform?

Comment: The numerator is decidedly *not* a mass integral but rather a first moment integral. You cannot determine the center of mass without knowing how the mass is distributed in a particular direction, which is why you need to compute the first moment. The $x$-coordinate of the center of mass is *not* the point where the overall masses to the left and to the right are equal; that would completely disregard the spatial distribution of the mass.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, one last question, when we say moment are we referring to the moment of inertia and if so would the formula not be mr^2

In a derivation for the centre of mass I saw they assumed the moment was the summation of mass * the distance away from a particular point. When googling moment, I either get moment of inertia which uses the summation of mr^2

Why do we sum m*r in this case instead?

Comment: It's not the moment of inertia, which is more related to the *second* moment. Have you heard the term "torque" from physics? First moment is the same thing. A force applied to the center of mass (such as gravity, for all intents and purposes) generates zero moment, or torque, and therefore does not make the object rotate. The reason we need the (first) moment integral is because we want to find the (weighted) "average" $x$-coordinate. If you check the dimensions of the expression, that is exactly what we get after dividing by the total mass.

Comment: Yes I have heard of torque but the reason I was confused was due to the fact that Torque = m * a * r where r is distance m is mass and a is acceleration. In the derivation I watched there was no mention of acceleration, rather they just stated the formula to be moment = mass x distance, I get that acceleration doesn’t matter if it is the same at every point, so do we just neglect to write a in the formula because it doesn’t matter in this case?

Comment: There does not need to be acceleration $a$. "Torque" just refers to a force applied at a distance. Since the force of gravity has $W \propto m$, we can think of the (first) moment of mass about a point as being given by $\int_m \vec{r} (m) d m$. The *center* of mass (equal to the center of gravity, in a uniform gravitational field) is simply this moment divided by the total mass. It's the point where if you placed a pivot on the object, the object would not feel a torque from gravity.